# Springboot LDAP timeout cerrar conexión

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap

Estoy intentando cerrar la conexión levantada con el LDAP de mi aplicación después de 5 segundos, añado los siguiente valores al método de la clase de autenticación pero no funciona, ¿alguna idea?

```
@Bean
public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("ldap.url"));
    contextSource.setBase(env.getProperty("ldap.userSearchBase"));
    contextSource.setUserDn(env.getProperty("ldap.managerDn"));
    contextSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ldap.managerPassword"));     
    
    contextSource.setPooled(false);
    Map<String, Object> environment = new HashMap<>();
    environment.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "5000");
    environment.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "5000");
    contextSource.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(environment);
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    
    return contextSource;
}
```

EDITO: Lo que necesito es poder **cerrar la sesión de usuario** pasados x segundos.

Comment: Esos timeouts son tiempos de espera para que el intento de conexión/obtención de info falle después de N milisegundos de esperar al servidor sin recibir respuesta. No son lo que supones y tocaba leer la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/readtimeout.html) pa no morir engañados ;)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pues vaya... me refería entonces a cerrar la sesión de un usuario depués de n segundos...